# What is the definition of plain cereal? What is the definition of plain wheat germ?

Tags: vocabulary

Searching on the internet left me with no answers.

Later edit : plain cereal in this context : http://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/breakfast-cereals/1562/2

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. In what context have you encountered these terms? I imagine *plain cereal* would something different to agronomers, botanists, and schoolchildren.

Comment: I apologize, in this context : http://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/breakfast-cereals/1562/2 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [Difference Between Plain Wheat Germ & Crude Wheat Germ](http://www.ehow.com/list_7597684_difference-germ-crude-wheat-germ.html) for a fuller explanation, but basically, ***plain*** seems to be the "processed, cooked, toasted" version of the original ***crude*** grains.

According to that page, ***plain/toasted*** has shedloads more vitamins and stuff, but also more calories, so you might go for ***crude/raw*** if you're looking to lose weight.